# Sort multidimensional array on column values DESC, then by length of another column DESC

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort some data that is not coming from a database, but is structured like a sql result set.

In MySQL, I would write a query as follows to sort the data by two columns:

```
SELECT product, qty FROM stock ORDER BY qty DESC, LENGTH(product) DESC
```

However, in this case, I need to perform this sorting logic with php.  Specifically, the rows are sorted first by descending `qty`, and then by the length of `name` descending.

Unsorted Input:

```
[
    ['name' => 'foo bar', 'qty' => 6],
    ['name' => 'foo bar bar foo', 'qty' => 10],
    ['name' => 'b', 'qty' => 5],
    ['name' => 'foo', 'qty' => 10],
    ['name' => 'bar', 'qty' => 6],
    ['name' => 'foo bar bar bar foo', 'qty' => 6],
]
```

After sorting, I need to restructure the data with the `name` values as keys and the `qty` values as values of a flat, associative array
The finished array would look something like this:

Desired Output:

```
[
    'foo bar bar foo' => 10,
    'foo' => 10,
    'foo bar bar bar foo' => 6,
    'foo bar' => 6,
    'bar' => 6,
    'b' => 5
]
```

Comment: also, is there a particular reason you want to do it in PHP?

Comment: @Ascherer: The data is not present in MySQL, and I want to avoid the transfer time of putting it all in there. My SELECT statement was just an example.

Comment: ahh, k. That makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the answers to this question: [PHP array multiple sort - by value then by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key), it seems [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort) is the way to go.  (I'm not really sure how `array_multisort` works, I just kinda hacked this up, and it seems to work).

Try this:

```
$arr = array(
  'foo bar' => 6,
  'foo' => 10,
  'bar' => 6,
  'b' => 5,
  'foo bar bar bar foo' => 6,
  'foo bar bar foo' => 10
);

array_multisort(array_values($arr), SORT_DESC,
  array_map(create_function('$v', 'return strlen($v);'), array_keys($arr)),
  SORT_DESC, $arr);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/mAttNIV7

UPDATE: Added `array_map` to make it sort by the length of the string, before it was just doing:

`$str1 > $str2` instead of `strlen($str1) > strlen($str2)`.

UPDATE 2: In PHP >= 5.3, you can replace `create_function` with a real anonymous function.

```
array_map(function($v){return strlen($v);}, array_keys($arr))
```

Demo 2: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6qrFwj

Comment: hmm, yeah that way works better than mine with the original array, i originally avoided this cause i didnt think it would sort the strings by length, but it looks like it is lol

Comment: @Ascherer: It was originally sorting the strings by doing `$a > $b`, it wasn't sorting by length, it just happened to be in that order.  I added an `array_map` to make it sort by legnth.

Comment: @Ascherer: `usort` can't sort on both the keys and the values, though.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at php's  `usort` and `uasort`.

You should be able to define a function that can sort it like that

Not sure if it would work easily with that current array but this one it would

```
$array = array(
 array('name' => 'foo bar bar foo', 'qty' => 10 ),
 array('name' => 'foo', 'qty' => 6),
 array('name' => 'foo bar bar foo', 'qty' => 6 ),
 array('name' => 'foo bar', 'qty' => 6 )
);

uasort($array, 'arraySort');

function arraySort($a, $b)
{
    if($a['qty'] > $b['qty'])
        return 1;
    elseif($a['qty'] < $b['qty'])
        return -1;
    else
        if(strlen($a['name']) >= strlen($b['name']))
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One limitation while sorting the keys on the basis of length is that: equal length keys are not re-ordered. Say we need to order the keys by length in `descending` order.

```
$arr = array(
    "foo 0" => "apple",
    "foo 1" => "ball",
    "foo 2 foo 0 foo 0" => "cat",
    "foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0" => "dog",
    "foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1" => "elephant",
    "foo 2 foo 1 foo 0" => "fish",
    "foo 2 foo 1 foo 1" => "giraffe"
);

debug($arr, "before sort");
$arrBad = $arr;
sortKeysDescBAD($arrBad);
debug($arrBad, "after BAD sort");
sortKeysDescGOOD($arr);
debug($arr, "after GOOD sort 2");

function sortKeysDescBAD(&$arrNew) {
    $arrKeysLength = array_map('strlen', array_keys($arrNew));
    array_multisort($arrKeysLength, SORT_DESC, $arrNew);
    //return max($arrKeysLength);
}

function sortKeysDescGOOD(&$arrNew) {
    uksort($arrNew, function($a, $b) {
        $lenA = strlen($a); $lenB = strlen($b);
        if($lenA == $lenB) {
            // If equal length, sort again by descending
            $arrOrig = array($a, $b);
            $arrSort = $arrOrig;
            rsort($arrSort);
            if($arrOrig[0] !== $arrSort[0]) return 1;
        } else {
            // If not equal length, simple
            return $lenB - $lenA;
        }
    });
}

function debug($arr, $title = "") {
    if($title !== "") echo "<br/><strong>{$title}</strong><br/>";
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr); echo "</pre><hr/>";
}
```

**Output will be:**

```
before sort
Array
(
    [foo 0] => apple
    [foo 1] => ball
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 0] => cat
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0] => dog
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1] => elephant
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 0] => fish
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 1] => giraffe
)

after BAD sort
Array
(
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0] => dog
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1] => elephant
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 0] => cat
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 0] => fish
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 1] => giraffe
    [foo 0] => apple
    [foo 1] => ball
)

after GOOD sort
Array
(
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 1] => elephant
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 1 foo 0] => dog
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 1] => giraffe
    [foo 2 foo 1 foo 0] => fish
    [foo 2 foo 0 foo 0] => cat
    [foo 1] => ball
    [foo 0] => apple
)
```

Notice the order of `elephant` and `dog` for example (or others) in two sorting methods. The second method looks better. There may be easier ways to solve this but hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

Starting from an input array that resembles a sql result set, you can cleanly use `usort()` containing a 3-way comparison then a conditional secondary 3-way comparison.  When done, you can isolate the `qty` column of data as the values and (assuming all of the `name` values are unique) use the `name` column as the assigned keys using `array_column()`.  When comparing, write the `$b` data on the left of the operator and the `$a` on the right to achieve a descending sort order.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dIMiO))

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'foo bar bar foo', 'qty' => 6],
    ['name' => 'bah', 'qty' => 5],
    ['name' => 'foo foo bar foo', 'qty' => 10],
    ['name' => 'foo', 'qty' => 6],
    ['name' => 'foo bar', 'qty' => 6],
    ['name' => 'bar', 'qty' => 11],
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['qty'] <=> $a['qty'] ?: strlen($b['name']) <=> strlen($a['name']);
});

var_export(array_column($array, 'qty', 'name'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'bar' => 11,
  'foo foo bar foo' => 10,
  'foo bar bar foo' => 6,
  'foo bar' => 6,
  'foo' => 6,
  'bah' => 5,
)
```

The advantage of using `comparison1 ?: comparison2` is that the function calls in `comparison2` are not executed unless a tiebreak is necessary -- this improves efficiency.  Alternatively, using `array_multisort()` will unconditionally call `strlen()` on all `qty` values -- even if they are not needed for sorting.

It is perfectly valid to execute the sort with a single spaceship operator, but the following technique will make two function calls every time a comparison is made.  This will be less efficient than my above snippet, so **I do not recommend the following snippet**.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return [$b['qty'], strlen($b['name']] <=> [$a['qty'], strlen($a['name'])];
});
```

---

p.s. Of course this can be done with `array_multisort()` as well, I just find the syntax to be less concise.

```
array_multisort(
    array_column($array, 'qty'),
    SORT_DESC,
    array_map(
        function($row) {
            return strlen($row['name']);
        },
        $array
    ),
    SORT_DESC,
    $array
);

var_export(array_column($array, 'qty', 'name'));
```

Answer (score -2):

use the sort function in php. make sure you use the TRUE as the second parameter to preserve the keys.

Comment: [`sort`](http://php.net/sort) doesn't have a "preserve keys" parameter.  If you want to do that, you'd use [`asort`](http://php.net/asort).