# php array sort in two ways

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
$arr = array(

    'Alcatel' => '0',
    'Apple' =>   '4542',
    'LG' =>      '0',
    'Nokia' =>   '0',
    'Samsung' => '2760',
    'Siemens' => '0',
    'Sony' =>    '0',

);
```

all the keys are alphabetically ordered, but the values are not.
I want to:
1- maintain associations
2- sort the array by values HIGH to LOW
3- maintain alphabetical order for zero-value entries

to get:

```
$arr = array(

    'Apple' =>   '4542',
    'Samsung' => '2760',
    'Alcatel' => '0',
    'LG' =>      '0',
    'Nokia' =>   '0',
    'Siemens' => '0',
    'Sony' =>    '0',

);
```

now when I used arsort($arr);

I got:

```
$arr = array(
  'Apple' =>   '4542',
  'Samsung' => '2760',
  'Siemens' => '0',
  'Sony' =>    '0',
  'Nokia' =>   '0',
  'LG' =>      '0',
  'Alcatel' => '0',
);
```

So I got goals 1 and 2 and NOT 3

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: [uasort](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and [uksort](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) don't do the trick?

Comment: This maybe be of some help to achieve #3

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key

Comment: Looking at the manual for uksort there seems to be several functions in the comments that does exactly this, and you did of course read the manual first.

Comment: thanks for suggestions but may I have some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally did it:

Because $arr is a combination of 2 arrays, $titles and $values:

```
array_multisort($values, SORT_DESC, $titles, SORT_ASC, $arr);
```

this finally works!

Answer (score 0):

For the more general case, if you didn't have the keys and values already handy in separate source arrays, you would need a custom comparison function.  There are versions of `sort` that pass the keys to the comparison function, and versions that pass the values, but you need both, and there isn't one that passes both in.

Since `uksort` passes the keys, you can look up the values, but if you access the array being sorted from the comparison function, you get unreliable results and a warning from PHP.  So you need to make a copy.

The cleanest solution I could think of was to wrap the copy/access up in a closure (so this requires 5.4):

```
$arr = array(
    'Alcatel' => '0',
    'Apple' =>   '4542',
    'LG' =>      '0',
    'Nokia' =>   '0',
    'Samsung' => '2760',
    'Siemens' => '0',
    'Sony' =>    '0',
  );

  function mkcmp($arr) {
    return function($k1, $k2) use ($arr) {
      $v1 = $arr[$k1];
      $v2 = $arr[$k2];

      if ($v1 > $v2) {
        return -1;
      } else if ($v1 < $v2) {
        return 1;
      } else if ($k1 < $k2) {
        return -1;
      } else if ($k1 == $k2) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    };
  }

  uksort($arr, mkcmp($arr));
```

And here's the output of `print_r($arr)` after the sort:

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => 4542
    [Samsung] => 2760
    [Alcatel] => 0
    [LG] => 0
    [Nokia] => 0
    [Siemens] => 0
    [Sony] => 0
)
```