# Sort array by values ASC, then keys ASC

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

SO,

**The problem**

I have an issue with custom array sorting. I have an array:

```
$rgData = [
  3 => 1,
  5 => 0,
  1 => 2,
  9 => 0,
  0 => 1,
  4 => 2,
  2 => 1,
  7 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  8 => 0,
];
```

-it contain keys with their counts (actually, it came after some operations with `array_count_values`). Now I want to sort it that:

- Lower values comes first (i.e. usual ascending sort which can be done with `asort()`)
- Within one value, keys should be sorted ascending (here I need help)

For sample above result should be:

```
[5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 0=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1, 1=>2, 4=>2]
```

**My approach**

I have no idea how to resolve this with sort by user-defined since `usort` or `uasort` accept only values for comparing while `uksort` - only keys and I need both of them in my comparison function. The only way that I have now - is to do this:

```
$rgData = ['3'=>1, '5'=>0, '1'=>2, '9'=>0, '0'=>1, '4'=>2, '2'=>1, '7'=>0, '6'=>0, '8'=>0];
$rgTemp = [];
asort($rgData);
$i     = 0;
$mPrev = current($rgData);
foreach($rgData as $mKey=>$mValue)
{
        $rgTemp[$mPrev==$mValue?$i:++$i][$mKey] = $mValue;
        $mPrev = $mValue;
}
$rgTemp = array_map(function($rgX)
{
        ksort($rgX);
        return $rgX;
}, $rgTemp);
$rgData = [];
//can't use call_user_func_array('array_merge', $rgTemp) - it spoils numeric keys
foreach($rgTemp as $rgX)
{
        foreach($rgX as $mKey=>$mValue)
        {
                $rgData[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
}
//var_dump($rgData);
```

-i.e. split array by values first, then do the stuff.

**The question**

How to do this in more easy way? I used `asort` + cycled `ksort` via `array_map` with final gathering loop. Temp array also used. It looks weird. I hope simpler method exists.

Comment: Most concisely from PHP7.4 and up: [`uksort($rgData, fn($a, $b) => [$rgData[$a], $a] <=> [$rgData[$a], $a]);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315474/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.  It sorts by the keys, but we can access the value inside the function, so we can use that as our sort criteria too.

```
uksort($rgData, function($a, $b) use($rgData){
    $aVal = $rgData[$a];
    $bVal = $rgData[$b];

    // Compare the values
    if($aVal === $bVal){
        // If they are the same, compare the keys
        return $a - $b;
    }
    // Otherwise compare the values
    return $aVal - $bVal;
});
```