# Sort an associative array by value in descending and preserve order when values are same

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an associative array and there is an inbuilt function to achieve the same viz. `arsort()`, but the problem with this function is that it doesn't maintain the original key order when values are same. 
e.g.

```
$l = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 2,
    'd' => 4,
    'e' => 5,
    'f' => 5
];
```

The result which I want is :

```
$l = [
    'e' => 5,
    'f' => 5,
    'd' => 4,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 2,
    'a' => 1
];
```

`arsort()` gives the result in descending order but it randomly arranges the element when values are same.
This question is not a duplicate of [PHP array multiple sort - by value then by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key). In that question it is asking for same numeric value to be sorted alphabetically but in my question I am asking values to sorted according to the original order if they are same.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: I can't reproduce this. for your example, I get the results you are wanting (e,f,d,b,c,a) with arsort

Comment: Definitely reproducible https://3v4l.org/kqZLd

Comment: I am getting e,f,d,c,b,a but it is not random for me, I tried refreshing many times. Probably we need to write a custom function if that is the case and you are particular about the keys to use in a specific order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array multiple sort - by value then by key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key)

Comment: @dont-panic This question is slightly different from the one which you provided. In that question it is asking for  same numeric value to be sorted alphabetically but in my question I am asking values to sorted according to the original order if they are same.

Comment: @jeff-puckett-ii Please use this array. $l = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 2,
    'd' => 4,
    'g' => 5,
    'e' => 5,
    'f' => 5
]; The result which I want is  g, e, f, d, b, c, a .

Comment: Yes, I agree that that's different. Sorry I overlooked the difference initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but I think this should work to maintain the original key order within groups of the same value. I'll start with this array for example:

```
$l = [ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 4, 'g' => 5, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 5 ];
```

1. Group the array by value:

   ```
   foreach ($l as $k => $v) {
       $groups[$v][] = $k;
   }
   ```

   Because the `foreach` loop reads the array sequentially, the keys will be inserted in their respective groups in the correct order, and this will yield:

   ```
   [1 => ['a'], 2 => ['b', 'c'], 4 => ['d'], 5 => ['g', 'e', 'f'] ];
   ```
2. sort the groups in descending order by key:

   ```
   krsort($groups);
   ```
3. Reassemble the sorted array from the grouped array with a nested loop:

   ```
   foreach ($groups as $value => $group) {
       foreach ($group as $key) {
           $sorted[$key] = $value;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @dont-panic Thanks a lot for answer with detailed explanation, it's working fine..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_multisort`. The function can be a bit confusing, and really hard to explain, but it orders multiple arrays, and the first array provided gets sorted based on the order of subsequent arrays.

Try:

```
array_multisort($l, SORT_DESC, array_keys($l));
```

See the example here: https://3v4l.org/oV8Od

It sorts the array by values descending, then is updated by the sort on the keys of the array.

Comment: It is not working as expected for the array 
$l = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 2,
    'd' => 4,
    'g' => 5,
    'e' => 5,
    'f' => 5
]; 
I want the answer to be g, e, f, d, b, c, a but it is giving me e, f, g, d, b, c, a.

Comment: In that case, you have custom logic ('g' is usually after 'e' and 'g'), so you'll need to implement some custom sorting algorthm

Comment: Could you please help me in writing that logic. My problem statement is simple that if value are same then they follow the same order as the original array.

Comment: it's not custom logic, it just that the order should be by value, not by key