# Is there any function where I can sort array by value and if values are same it should print in the same order as they are supplied in the array?

Tags: php

I have currently looking for a function which sort the array in the following order:
for example:I have an array

```
$result=array("dddd"=>2,"ccc"=>4,"ddd"=>5,"pks"=>3,"sss"=>2,"test"=>2);
```

it should gives this output.

```
Array
(
    [ddd] => 5
    [ccc] => 4
    [pks] => 3
    [dddd] => 2
    [sss] => 2
    [test] => 2
)
```

I have tried arsort but it does not give the required output.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want the result sorted by values in reverse order and for duplicate values with the keys sorted in ascending order? Try this:

```
$result=array("dddd"=>2,"ccc"=>4,"ddd"=>5,"pks"=>3,"sss"=>2,"test"=>2);

array_multisort(array_values($result), SORT_DESC, array_keys($result), SORT_ASC, $result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [ddd] => 5
    [ccc] => 4
    [pks] => 3
    [dddd] => 2
    [sss] => 2
    [test] => 2
)
```

Edit: while re-reading the title of your question, I realize that you perhaps don't want to sort duplicate values using their keys, but using the initial position in the original array. In that case your question is a probably a duplicate of: [Sort an associative array by value in descending and preserve order when values are same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446580/)

Answer (score -1):

Try the asort function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

It allows sorting associative array with value. It keeps the order of the keys

Comment: The [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) PHP function **does not** preserve the original order of the keys. This is specified in the documentation in a note that reads: *"If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined."*

Comment: Well, when I said "it keeps the order of the keys", I was referring to this line in the documentation: "asort — Sort an array and maintain index association". It means when the array is sorted using asort, the keys remain assigned to the same values. Only the array values are sorted