# Need to change array key value during asort function

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have below array,

```
$arr = Array ( [0] => 248 [1] => 247 )
```

Using asort() I get below result,

```
$arr = Array ( [1] => 247 [0] => 248 )
```

But I need the below format,

```
$arr = Array ( [0] => 247 [1] => 248 )
```

Need to sort only the value not key. Is there any default function in php for my expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array multiple sort - by value then by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to reset the keys after sorting.

```
<?php

$arr = [248, 247];

asort($arr);

print_r(array_values($arr));
```

will give:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 247
    [1] => 248
)
```

---

BTW, I ain't sure why you use [`asort`](http://php.net/asort), but when you use [`sort`](http://php.net/sort) function to sort, it resets the keys.

From the manual:

> **asort** - Sort an array and maintain index association
>
> **sort** - Sort an array **(Your Exact Need)**

Answer (score 4):

Use just sort() function.

You can see more about sorting functions in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)