# php array multisort didn't return correct results when key has combination of integers and strings

Tags: php, arrays, array-multisort

I want to sort an array by ascending order of keys and descending order of values

below is my array before sorting

```
[undefined] => 166
[template] => 2
[indesign] => 1
[product] => 1
[2] => 3
[4] => 3
[66] => 2
[34] => 1
[2222] => 1
```

I used below code for sorting

```
 array_multisort(array_values($data), SORT_DESC, array_keys($data), SORT_ASC, $data);
```

here the sorted output

```
   [undefined] => 166
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [template] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [indesign] => 1
    [product] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
```

keys which has integers has changed, How can I overcome this?

Comment: You are sorting by values first, not keys. Swap the arguments. Also look at SORT_NATURAL

Comment: @AbraCadaver, swaping aragument didnt work. natsort() does this support of sorting with both key and value same time ?

Comment: You say you want keys descending and then values ascending but you have them backwards, then you need to `SORT_ASC | SORT_NATURAL` for keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);

array_multisort($values, SORT_DESC, $keys, SORT_ASC | SORT_NATURAL);

$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [undefined] => 166
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [66] => 2
    [template] => 2
    [34] => 1
    [2222] => 1
    [indesign] => 1
    [product] => 1
)
```

Comment: Right answer (upvoted). I think this could be even better if you explain the OP why his code didn't work and this does (maybe even add link to `array_multisort` documantation...)

Comment: Also, they state _ascending order of keys and descending order of values_  so keys should be first.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, can't confirm your idea. The sample output in the end of question says the opposite. It looks like OP googled https://stackoverflow.com/a/6611077/1597430 but didn't read comments.